# Trigger help for invoice numbering system with yearly rollback

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I want to create a trigger to help facilitate an invoice numbering system such that I can do this:

2014-1, 2014-2, 2014-3, 2015-1

The ID number needs to rollback by year. For compatibility reasons I cannot use a composite key.

I'm trying a trigger like this:

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update invoices set new.number = (SELECT MAX(NUM) FROM invoices WHERE DATEPART(year, new.date) = DATEPART(year, date)) + 1;
END
```

Date in my table is the DATE format in MySQL. I'm trying to use that so it'll see the date of the new row being inserted, find the highest number for that year and set it so the new one is one higher.

however, on an insert of a new row I'm getting an error related to the trigger. Any ideas on how to fix this or ideas on how to better implement this?

Comment: so the -1/-2/-3 cycle around? 2016-2, 2017-3, 2018-1, etc...? or you want to reset to -1 when the first invoice of any particular year arrives?

Comment: @MarcB Yes that is correct.

Comment: which is correct? you want the cycle, or the yearly reset?

Comment: Sorry, I want it to reset on the year. So when a new year comes, invoices start at 1 again.

Comment: you'd probably want `where year(max(invoices.date)) <> year(new.date)` or something. if the years are different, then you've moved into "next" year, and the number should be reset. if the years are the same, then you're in the "same" year, and just increment the number.

Comment: I get an error `ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'invoices' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.` Maybe im doing the syntax for a trigger wrong? I changed my where to the one you gave.